# System Error - Unknown Hard Error

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash, windows-error-reporting, error-logging

Over the past two weeks I have randomly received a popup containing the text: `System Error : Unknown Hard Error`. After clicking OK, everything continues to run fine on the machine (no blue screens, no system restarts or anything). I hadn't noticed it before a week ago but now that I've received it twice I'm concerned about what could be causing it. I have not updated Windows recently.

Some answers suggested this could have been caused by failing hard drives. I have several hard drives in the computer but they are all functioning properly (according to `wmic diskdrive get status` and `Rick click on Disk -> Properties -> Tools -> Error Checking -> Check`), so I think all my drives are OK.

I went into Windows event viewer and there is this information in the xml view for the system event in the Windows log section corresponding to me receiving the popup:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Popup" Guid="{47BFA2B7-BD54-4FAC-B70B-29021084CA8F}" /> 
  <EventID>26</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-01-21T23:11:44.493358200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>83652</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="136" ThreadID="1460" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>MY-PC-NAME</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="Caption">Commandline.exe - System Error</Data> 
  <Data Name="Message">Unknown Hard Error</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

The process ID 136 corresponds to "Client Server Runtime Process" located at `C:\Windows\System32\csrss.exe`. I only have one program titled `Commandline.exe` on my computer, which is the Cinema 4D command line render executable, which was running both times I received the error. However, the C4D render did not fail and continued as though nothing happened after clicking the OK on the message box, so I'm not sure if it is truly related to that or not.

Although I only recall seeing this popup twice to date, I exported the Windows system log and searched for "Unknown Hard Error", and apparently I've encountered it a lot of times in the past as well:

```
Information     1/21/2023 5:11:44 PM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: Commandline.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     1/17/2023 7:46:11 PM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: Commandline.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     10/29/2022 4:23:47 PM   Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     10/28/2022 8:05:41 PM   Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     5/29/2022 12:56:43 PM   Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     2/3/2022 9:01:24 PM     Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     9/2/2021 7:30:48 PM     Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     9/2/2021 5:01:43 AM     Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: ShellExperienceHost.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     9/1/2021 7:03:41 AM     Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/30/2021 7:34:13 PM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/29/2021 3:46:37 AM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/29/2021 3:20:09 AM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: ShellExperienceHost.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/28/2021 12:46:12 PM   Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/9/2021 8:50:37 PM     Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/9/2021 10:25:11 AM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     8/6/2021 2:47:12 AM     Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     7/23/2021 8:00:45 AM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: SearchUI.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     4/30/2021 7:40:03 PM    Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     4/30/2021 12:52:12 AM   Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
Information     4/30/2021 12:17:57 AM   Application Popup       26      None    Application popup: CINEMA 4D.exe - System Error : Unknown Hard Error
```

As mentioned, Cinema 4D and Commandline.exe are related, but apparently this has appeared from several other programs as well (`ShellExperienceHost.exe` and `SearchUI.exe`).

I really don't have any clue what could be causing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: In my world, strange lockups and failures are signs of overheating components. Time toclean out all dustbins from inside the cabinet / laptop?

Comment: @Hannu, this is a desktop that I clean regularly. The CPU and GPU are both under full load since I'm doing CPU and GPU renders simultaneously, but the CPU  (i7 5960x) temp is 74 C and the GPUs (2x GTX 970s) are 78 C and 77 C. The CPU and GPU are from 2015, so it's possible they are just getting old and dying, but I don't know what tests I can do to confirm that given they are still functional. I suspect the error in my post is a software issue but I don't really know what else to look at.

Comment: @Hannu, it actually just happened again a few minutes ago. I noticed it happened right as the GPU renderer finished rendering a frame of the animation. I wonder if there is an error in the render engine I'm using that is particular to the scene I'm rendering. That would explain why I've seen it the past week so many times but not much prior to that (this particular scene I'm rendering has been going for about a week now). So it may just be a bug in the gpu render plugin I'm using.

Comment: I've seen such mishaps in a machine that had been sitting on the same table-top for years; picking out the DIMM -modules in that machine, and running a pencil earaser over the edge contacts resurrected that machine. That was in times before GPU's though... ;-)